# Why is the refueling point of this A320 on the left wing instead of the right?

Tags: airbus-a320, fuel-systems, refueling

Every other A320 I've seen has the refueling done in the right wing but not this one. Why?

Registration YL-LDN
[image]

Comment: I was looking at the plane for some words, and there are none so its possible the photo was flipped horizontally.  Then I saw the "AirBP" wording on the fuel bowser so its just a blank paint job, possibly brand new or at least being re-painted.

Comment: @Criggie The fuel truck has "air BP" written on it, therefore if the the photo initially contained both the aircraft and the truck, it's definitely not flipped.

Answer (score 17):

It's possible that an A320 can be refueled from a refueling point located on either wing, as installed.

[image]

[(Source)](https://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/A320-Fuel.pdf)

*(Highlighting is mine)*